# Why is 'getTimezoneOffset' implemented in the Date.prototype and not as a static method of Date?

Tags: javascript, date

Why was the method `getTimezoneOffset` implemented as a method of the Date prototype object and not as a static method of the Date object since it will always return the difference of the current host system and not the Date instance itself?

Is there any comprehensible reason for it?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

(Btw, I tagged "Java" because I heard that many Date functions in JavaScript are inspired by Java)

Answer (score 6):

Because of Daylight Saving Time.
The UTC offset will be different in the same time zone depending on whether the date is before or after the DST change.

Quoting further down in that MDN page:

> The time zone offset returned is the one that applies for the Date that it's called on. Where the host system is configured for daylight saving, the offset will change depending on the date and time that the Date represents and that daylight saving applies.